# GtkComboBox with entry causes `gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed`

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to write a ComboBox with entry, containing Text with a list store. My code is based on the code from [the official gtk-demo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/gtk-3-24/demos/gtk-demo/combobox.c)

Problem:

When I create a combo box with entry,

- All entries are centric
- I cannot select any entries
- Command line shows gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed

#### Code

Here is, how I create my combo boxes (currently with a hard-coded switch for testing.

```
if (FALSE)
    {
       // works fine
       combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model (model);
    }
    else
    {
       // Entries are centric
       // Cannot select entries
       // command line shows gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed
       combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model_and_entry (model);
    }
```

#### Full Code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


enum
{
  TEXT_COL,
  ICON_NAME_COL

};



static GtkTreeModel *
create_icon_store (void)
{    
  const gchar *labels[6] = {
    ("Warning"),
    ("Stop"),
    ("New"),
    ("Clear"),
    ("Open")
  };

  GtkTreeIter iter;
  GtkListStore *store;
  gint i;

  store = gtk_list_store_new (1, G_TYPE_STRING);

  for (i = 0; i < G_N_ELEMENTS (labels); i++)
    {
       gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
       gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                           TEXT_COL, (labels[i]),
                           -1);   
    }

  return GTK_TREE_MODEL (store);
}



void create_gui(GtkContainer *container)
{
   GtkWidget *combo;
   GtkTreeModel *model;
   GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
   GtkTreeIter iter;

    model = create_icon_store ();
    if (FALSE)
    {
       // works fine
       combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model (model);
    }
    else
    {
       // Entries are centric
       // Cannot select entries
       // command line shows gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed
       combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model_and_entry (model);
    }
    
    g_object_unref (model);
    gtk_container_add (container, combo);


    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start (GTK_CELL_LAYOUT (combo), renderer, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes (GTK_CELL_LAYOUT (combo), renderer,
                                    "text", TEXT_COL,
                                    NULL);

    gtk_combo_box_set_active (GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo), 0);   
    
}


/**
 *  standard stuff. Check out create_gui() 
 **/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  GtkWidget * box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);

  create_gui (GTK_CONTAINER (box));

  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                    G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT (window));

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Glade as GUI design tool. By default the combofields attribute

> Entry Text Column = -1

Make this:

> Entry Text Column = 0

this avoids the warning message:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: 11:23:13.657: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

1. You need to tell which colum GtkEntry (of the ComboBox) should use:

   - You do that with `gtk_combo_box_set_entry_text_column`
   - You should also specify `gtk_combo_box_set_id_column` (don't know why, but gtk does so)
2. When you used `gtk_combo_box_set_entry_text_column`, you don't need your own renderer anymore; otherwise you will have two column shown.

#### General Code

Here is a function, that will create a combo box with entry for a list store with one text column (`G_TYPE_STRING`)

```
/**
 * Creates a combo box for list store with one text column.
 *    (= ComboBoxText)
 * The combo box will own `model`. No `g_object_unref` needed.
 */
GtkComboBox *
create_combo_box_with_entry(GtkListStore *model)
{
   GtkWidget *combo;   

   combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model_and_entry (GTK_TREE_MODEL (model));   
   g_object_unref (model);

   // Note: You don't need to use an a renderer, if you have 
   //      a simple ComboBox for text with an entry, because
   //      the following functions will setup a renderer     
   gtk_combo_box_set_entry_text_column (GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo), 0);
   gtk_combo_box_set_id_column (GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo), 0);

   return GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo);
}
```

Comment: I am not certain that I can follow this post at all. You are asking something, and then you give an explanation to it. This sounds like a [Tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutorial) to me, which definitely is not what SO stands for.

Comment: I was asking something, figured out the solution on my own, generalized it, posted it. Please point to the place that says, I should not properly answer my own questions, if I found a solution in the meantime.

Comment: It is not about what are you doing, more over about how you did it.

Comment: Self-answering is in fact [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), @Michi